# New-ComplianceSearchAction Invalid parameter 'ShareRootPath'

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I run the following command for an existing search result "xxx":

```
New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "xxx" -export
```

I get the following error message:

*Die Aufgabe kann nicht ausgeführt werden. Ursache: Der Wert für den 
ShareRootPath-Parameter ist ungültig. Er sollte im*

Any ideas, what "ShareRootPath-parameter" means? There isn't such parameter in the documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use

```
Connect-IPPSSession
```

instead of

```
Connect-EXOPSSession
```

before executing the New-ComplianceSearchAction cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

This cmdlet is available in on-premises Exchange and in the cloud-based service. Some parameters and settings may be exclusive to one environment or the other.
You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/blob/master/exchange/exchange-ps/exchange/policy-and-compliance-content-search/New-ComplianceSearchAction.md) for help.

Comment: In the help, you have linked to, i cannot find the 'ShareRootPath' parameter.

Comment: As I said, it is possible to have such parameters in a particular environment. Unfortunately, I also did not find the corresponding parameters.